# Streaming a html5 animation with a loop

Tags: javascript

I am working on a website that keeps looping an animation.
I want users who access this website anytime, to show them from where the animation stops not start the animation again.
This is not only restricted to animation but other event.
I do not have the best way to ask this question, so pardon me.
Let's say a website runs a countup from 1 to infinity.
Let anyone who visit the website see from where the countup count is, not starting the countup from 1 again.
I do not know how to go about this and will appreciate some help.
I know it has to do with real time.
I have also searched google but not getting exactly what i want probably due to the incorrect keywords.
I will be available to answer any follow up questions you have.
Examples can be made JS or another relatable framework

EDIT: Had to add this scenario to have a better understanding.
Let's say the website shows a live stream of a movie being recorded with a camera.(Event not initiated by the client or the server).
Users will always see the same thing and the current scene of that movie without storing any data of users.
I can't determine what triggers it as the animation in this instance should have no beginning and end.

Another example is seeing a Simulated virtual soccer site. Everyone sees the same state of the game even though its not played live and it keeps loading new events to be bet on.

EDIT2:
Like i said, i do not have the best way to ask this question. Thanks to Randy for bringing up the way the question should be.
Question: How do i stream a html5 animation that also shows the same state of anim to all users while it keeps looping.
I know the  should do something like this but i do not have an idea of how to go about streaming created animation that are not from a valid source but probably a canvas tag.

EDIT 3: I think the issue shouldn't be how the animation is created. But this is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../phaser-3.50.0/dist/phaser.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        var config = {
            type: Phaser.AUTO,
            width: 600,
            height: 600,
            scene: {
                preload: preload,
                create: create,
                update: update
            }
        };

        var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

        function preload ()
        {
            this.load.image('sky', '../img/sky_up.png');
            this.load.image('road', '../img/road_sides.png');
        }

        function create ()
        {
            let image = this.add.image(this.cameras.main.width / 2, this.cameras.main.height / 2, 'sky')
            let scaleX = this.cameras.main.width / image.width
            let scaleY = this.cameras.main.height / image.height
            let scale = Math.max(scaleX, scaleY)
            image.setScale(scale).setScrollFactor(0);

            // this.add.image(0,0,'road');

            this.logo=this.add.sprite(0,0,"road");
            this.logo.x=this.world.centerX;
            
        }

        function update ()
        {
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @user3783243 - OP specifically states "_see from where the countup count is, not starting the countup from 1 again._" - my interpretation of that is any user, whether previous visitor or not, shall see the current counter value - not a new counter value per user. I could be wrong, but that needs clarification too.

Comment: Another question is, What action starts the timer and is that action required on the client or the server?

Comment: @RandyCasburn You are correct. Users all see the same thing - the current state of the animation or count down once loaded.

Comment: @RandyCasburn the action wouldnt be dependent on the database, server or client side.

Comment: What starts the timer? What action? Where does this occur? If on the client, which client of two simultaneous client's actions start this universal timer? The question lacks much needed detail.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I made an edit to explain better. Kindly check.

Comment: Your question is actually: "How do I **live stream an animation/video/arbitrary media**"?

Comment: Can you also clarify the sense of "animation" as used in question. Typically this means  an _animation effect produced in CSS_ , which may not be case here.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I would use some arbitrary point in time to represent start of the animation. For example, if animation is 60.000 frames 60 fps, you would start showing it at `let showFrame = Date.now() % 60000` for anyone who visits the website. This way everyone sees the same frame no matter when they joined the show, because it is based on universal timestamp.

*PREVIOUS ANSWER (not quite what OP was asking): With Javascript you can use window.localStorage as an easy way to store information about state. You can use beforeunload event to catch when user leaves the site and store current frame in client's local storage, from which you will get information where to start animation from, the next time client visits.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this wouldn't work. So if a user who hasnt visited the website before doesnt have the cookies stored. It means the animation will start from the beginning which isnt what i want. I want all users seeing the current state of the animation or loop. I have a problem determining what is to trigger this event.

Comment: I have edited my answer, please check if this is what you would need.

Comment: Thanks. Great suggestion. Animation is loaded with html5. Will frame work in this instance?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include code of how you load your animation? It will be easier to help if we know how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the example with the countup again. Every time an event starts, and you want to serve the content to all users, you need to use some kind of backend storage. Either you serve static content (not useful since your content seems to be dynamic) or you serve dynamic content that syncs with backend. This can be done easily with some kind of database, perhaps [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database).